# How to conditionally select indices from list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The variable general_h is a nested list initialised as shown below:-

```
general_h = [['?','?','?','?','?'] for i in range(len(specific_h))]
```

I want to get indices of general_h that still have value = ['?','?','?','?','?'] after a certain operation on it. I currently have this code for it:-

```
inds=[]
for i,hyp in enumerate(general_h):
    if hyp==['?','?','?','?','?']:
        inds.append(i)
```

How do I do this with list comprehension?

Comment: `inds = [i for i,hyp in enumerate(general_h) if hyp==['?','?','?','?','?']]`

Answer (score 1):

The for loop you're using is very close to the list comprehension used to do this:

```
inds = [i for i, hyp in enumerate(general_h) if hyp==['?','?','?','?','?']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
[i for i, hyp in enumerate(general_h) if hyp == ['?','?','?','?','?']]
```

You can find helpful information on list comprehensions on many pages, including [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Comment: Sorry, only saw the other answer posted after I submitted and the page refreshed!